# Bind error after stunnel restart on ios

Tags: ios, pthreads, stunnel

I have an stunnel build for iOS and it works perfectly, but when I try to restart it app crashes.

I'm starting it with pthread_create.
Here is the code to restart.

```
int ret;
ret = pthread_cancel(old_threadID);
if (ret != 0)
    NSLog(@"%i", ret);

void *res;
ret = pthread_join(old_threadID, &res);
if (ret != 0)
    NSLog(@"%i", ret);

if (res == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
    NSLog(@"main(): thread was canceled\n"); //This returns OK
else
    NSLog(@"main(): thread wasn't canceled (shouldn't happen!)\n");

//Begin new thread
pthread_t threadID;
//launch stunnel in a thread
int errorStunnel = pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, &stunnel_routine, (void *)fname);
NSLog(@"Error code!! : %i", errorStunnel); //error is 0.
```

After this App crashes. It crashes because can not start properly. as I see in stunnel.log because of this: "Error binding :443 to 127.0.0.1:12345
bind: Address already in use (48)"
Config file didn't change. So why ports are still binded with previous thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you close the socket when you canceled the thread?  The socket file descriptor is shared by the entire process.  If you just blow away the thread the socket is still open and bound to that port because the network layer has no idea nor concern with how many threads you are running.  It only knows that the process still has the fd open.

Comment: I think you are right about the problem. Is it possible to close socket without descriptor?

Comment: No, you need the fd.  Does stunnel not give you access to what it is using?  Why are you canceling the thread?  Are you just blowing it away or can you shut down properly and therefore allow a stunnel restart with a new thread?